# Why isn't USD an option for importing with Blender 3.4.1 on Linux?

Tags: import

I'm running Blender 3.4.1 on Linux attempting to import a USD file. My "File/Import" does not have USD as an option. Every tutorial, video, etc that I see just navigates to File/Import and selectes USD, but this isn't showing up.
Are there specific plugins required to import USD?
I have usd-core installed on my computer (using nVidia Omniverse for a variety of tasks) and these all work.

Blender 3.4.1 on my Mac has the option to import USD files, but not my linux build.

Does anyone know what's needed to enable USD on linux?

[image: Screenshot of File/Import]

Comment: Where did you get the Blender version (Website, snap, compile or so) it's working and i have by default  on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I use arch, and I installed it with pacman from the repo.  I also did a test downloading the latest version from blender.org.  It showed me the same thing

Comment: That is in the terminal output?

Answer (score 0):

if you type in USD Import/Export in f3 "Search" it comes up with your options, I just checked it out, but I haven't tried it though, so best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the root cause of this. The USD library (not the python package usd-core) is not yet ready for 'prime time' on Arch. The AUR package for usd doesn't install and is under active development.
Blender is recognizing that this library is not available, and hiding options accordingly.

Comment: Not a linux expert, but can't you just find another AUR in that case, or another form of package?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).